# Trying to load dynamic content on a specific site without affecting other sites

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I've followed a guide on how to add dynamic content to the cache and and show a error message through a fallback.json file (the error message is supposed to show up in same div where the dynamic content is).

The problem I am facing right now is that the website got multiple pages and I do only want to show the fallback text if I haven't loaded dynamic content on a specific site (the index site on this example). I am currently getting the fallback text on sites I haven't visited when I go offline.

***So my question is: 
How can the service worker act differently on different sites? 
And can I for example use a JS method instead of using a fallback.json file?***

Serviceworker.js:

```
const staticAssets = [
    './',
    './favicon.ico',
    './fallback.json'
];

// Call Install Event
self.addEventListener('install', async e => {
    console.log("From SW: Install Event");

    const cache = await caches.open('staticCache');
    cache.addAll(staticAssets);
});

// Call Fetch Event
self.addEventListener('fetch', async event => {
    console.log('Service Worker: Fetching');

    const req = event.request;
    const url = new URL(req.url);

    event.respondWith(networkFirst(req));
});

// Network first for latest articles - if not available get cached
async function networkFirst(req) {
    const cache = await caches.open('dynamicContent');

    try {
        // Try go through the network
        const res = await fetch(req,);
        // Store to cache
        cache.put(req, res.clone());
        return res;
    } catch (e) {
        // IF offline - return from cache
        const cachedResponse = await cache.match(req);
        // Return cachedresponce first, if no cache found - return fallback.json
        return cachedResponse || await caches.match('./fallback.json');
    }
}
```

And my manifest.json file:

```
{
    "articles": [
        {
            "title": "No articles found!!",
            "url": "",
            "urlToImage": "",
            "description": "Try reload your page once again when you are online."
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by using a IndexedDB. My mistake was trying to save dynamic content in the cache. The better solution for me was to handle and load data in a IndexedDB.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/working-with-indexeddb